Calculate inter-rater noise using Kahneman et al. (2021) approach
I need help calculating signal and noise based on the method described by Kahneman et al. (2021) in their book "Noise." They provide a technique for quantifying noise between raters assessing the same cases. Imagine five psychologists (raters) assessing the level of depression for 10 patients (cases). Here's the setup:
Let's say you have raters as rows and cases as columns. With zero noise, every rater agrees completely, so all variance is between cases (signal). Kahneman et al. further divide noise into (simplifying a bit):

rater noise: stable differences between raters, e.g. different means
for different people
residual noise: idiosyncratic noise that’s not    explained by
anything.

To calculate noise, they recommend:

Calculate the mean of the SD from each column (the SD of each case) (Total noise)
Calculate the SD of the means from each row (the means of each rater) (Rater noise)

You can then calculate residual noise by 1 - 2 = Residual noise.
My challenge is to calculate both noise and signal from a dataset. Additionally, I want to report noise as the intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC), but I am struggling to replicate Kahneman et al.'s method using other decomposition methods. For instance, using a random effects model with lme4::lmer() gives me different results.
I have simulated some data to illustrate my unsuccessful attempts. I am also questioning whether Kahneman et al.'s approach to analyzing noise is advisable, as I cannot find any other research utilizing this method.
Lastly, I need a sensible way to measure and report uncertainty. Is there a way to bootstrap my way to a confidence interval here?
# Load necessary packages
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
library(performance)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1234)

# Simulation parameters
n_raters <- 600
n_cases <- 30
n_obs <- n_raters * n_cases

# Simulate random effects
rater_effects <- rnorm(n_raters, mean = 0, sd = 1)  # rater random effects
case_effects <- rnorm(n_cases, mean = 0, sd = 2)    # case random effects

# Simulate dat
dat <- expand_grid(rater = factor(1:n_raters), case = factor(1:n_cases))
dat$ratereffect <- rater_effects[as.numeric(dat$rater)]
dat$caseeffect <- case_effects[as.numeric(dat$case)]
dat$residual <- rnorm(n_obs, mean = 0, sd = 3)  # Residual noise
dat$y <- dat$ratereffect + dat$caseeffect + dat$residual

dat

# Fit mixed-effects model (# This approximately retrives the parameters from the simulation)
model <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|rater) + (1|case), dat = dat)

# Display summary of the model
summary(model)

performance::icc(model,by_group = TRUE)
# Noice decomposition

# rater noise = 7.9 %
# case variance (signal) = 25 %
# residual noise = 100-(7.9+25) = 67.1 %

# Decomposition of noise only
# rater = 7.9/(7.9+67.1) = 10.5 %
# residual noise = 100 - 10.5 = 89.5 %

# Kahneman, Sibony, Cass (2021) calculation
dat <- dat |> 
  mutate(case = paste0("case",case)) |> 
  select(rater,case,y) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_from = y,names_from = case)

# calculate the mean of each row (rater)
dat <- dat |>
  select(-rater) |> 
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(row_mean = mean(c_across(everything())))

# take the sd of row means
sd_ratermean <- sd(dat$row_mean)

# take the standard deviation of each case
sd_case <- dat |>
  pivot_longer(everything()) |>
  summarise(sd_case = sd(value),.by = name) |>
  pull(sd_case)

# take the mean of case sd's
mean_case <- mean(sd_case)

total_noise <- mean_case
level_noise <- sd_ratermean
pattern_noise <- total_noise-level_noise

level_noise_percent <- level_noise/total_noise
pattern_noise_percent <- pattern_noise/total_noise

cat("level noise =",round(level_noise_percent,2),
    "\npattern noise =",round(pattern_noise_percent,2))

```


Are these methods meant to give the same answer? In any case, I think there is an error in your computation of the total, level and pattern noise: total_noise and level_noise are (on the scale) of std. deviations. So you need to square them to do the decomposition: pattern_noise^2 = total_noise^2 - level_noise^2.

Im not sure what I expect. What do you think of the Kahneman way of calculating noise? Based on your comment it might be sensible, but should squaring total noise and level noise. When I square, I get a percentage that's very close to the ICC calculation.

Is it fair to say that the Kahneman approach is erroneous, since it does the percentage calculations with standard deviations (non-additive) instead of variance (additive)?

Not sure your statement is correct. I checked out the kindle version from the library & I'm looking at Chapter 6, The Analysis of Noise. In the section "Judges differ: pattern noise" the formula is System Noise^2 = Level Noise^2 + Pattern Noise^2. It would be strange to do the decomposition on the std. dev. scale.

On the other hand, I'm also not sure there was a need to introduce a new term "noise" for what seems to be standard deviation. It creates some confusion as the "analysis of noise" is not "analysis of variance" but "analysis of std. deviation". Still trying out the calculations but

I think you are correct. The formula does indeed say to square each component. In my defence, Kahenman et al dont mention this step when going through the judges example (see page 74), which is the only calculated example in the book.

I too find the analysis of noise, described by Kahneman, Sibony and Sunstein in Noise: A Flaw in Human Judgment, idiosyncratic. Here's my attempt at understanding their calculation.
In Chapter 6, Kahneman et al. propose the following decomposition of noise in the severity of sentencing:
$$
\operatorname{System Noise}^2 = \operatorname{Level Noise}^2 + \operatorname{Pattern Noise}^2
$$

System noise is the variability in judgments of the same case by different judges.
Level noise is the variability in the average level of judgments by different judges. It's calculated as the std. deviation of the judges' mean sentences.
Pattern noise is the variability in judges' responses to particular cases. It's calculated by applying the decomposition formula.

How's the system noise calculated? Here are the two relevant paragraphs; I've copied them to make sure I don't mess up their exposition.

The essential result of this study is the large amount of noise observed within the judgments of each case. The measure of noise within each case is the standard deviation of the prison terms assigned to that case. For the average case, the mean sentence was 7.0 years, and the standard deviation around that mean was 3.4 years.
While you may well be familiar with the term standard deviation, you may find a concrete description useful. Imagine that you randomly pick two judges and compute the difference between their judgments of a case. Now repeat, for all pairs of judges and all cases, and average the results. This measure, the mean absolute difference, should give you a sense of the lottery that faces the defendant in a federal courtroom. Assuming that the judgments are normally distributed, it is 1.128 times the standard deviation, which implies that the average difference between two randomly chosen sentences of the same case will be 3.8 years.

Let's break down the second paragraph. For a single case, we take all the distinct pairs of judges and compute the (absolute) difference between the sentences they handed down to the offender in this case. If there are $n$ judges, we have $n(n-1)/2$ such pairs. The average of the $n(n-1)/2$ absolute differences is called Gini's mean difference, or GMD for short. (In R, we can calculate Gini's mean difference with Hmisc::GiniMd.) If there are $m$ cases, then we have $mn(n-1)/2$ pairs and the system noise is their average. Note: Since we cannot meaningfully compare sentences for difference cases, it would be incorrect to form $mn(mn-1)/2$ pairs.
This makes sense to me as Gini's mean difference is interpretable, efficient and robust (1, 2). It's also the case that a Normal distribution with std. deviation $\sigma$ has $\operatorname{GMD} = \sigma\left/\sqrt{\pi/4}\right. = 1.128\sigma$.
However, I have no idea how to calculate the standard deviation around the (overall) mean sentence. It sure sounds like taking the mean of the column (ie. case) std. deviations. However, averaging std. deviations doesn't sound right.
References

D. Kahneman, O. Sibony, and C. R. Sunstein. Noise: A Flaw in Human Judgment. Little, Brown and Company (2021).
K. Clancy, J. Bartolomeo, D. Richardson, and C. Wellford. Sentence decisionmaking: The logic of sentence decisions and the extent and sources of sentence disparity. The Journal of Criminal Law and Criminology, 72(2):524–554, 1981.
H. A. David. Gini’s mean difference rediscovered. Biometrika, 55(4):573–575, 1968.


PS: There's no implementation because I couldn't figure out how to compute the GMD conditional on case, ie. the average of the $mn(n-1)/2$ differences. And averaging Gini's mean differences seems just as suspect as averaging std. deviations.

For a more standard analysis I would use this model: m <- lmer(y ~ case + (1 | judge), data = dat).  I wouldn't conceptualize cases are random. What would the distribution of case effects be? Why would we expect it to be normal?

Then the level noise is sd_judge and the pattern noise is sd_resid. We can get those with VarCorr(m). Then the system noise is sqrt(sd_judge^2 + sd_resid^2) and the system GMD is sqrt(sd_judge^2 + sd_resid^2) / sqrt(pi/4). This isn't going to give the same answer as Kahneman et al though.
